# How to move variables from test functions to setUp function in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, oop, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to learn `Symfony` and `PHP` at the same time. I start by writing tests, and already have problem. I have this 2 repeating lines

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
```

which I can tell I would be using a lot. So I want this out to save testing speed and have nicer design. Here is my test file code:

### StaticControllerTest.php

```
<?php
namespace Qnsi\StaticBunde\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

#I want this class to only test /, other class to test About,Contact etc.
class StaticControllerIndexTest extends WebTestCase
{

  public function testStaticControllerControllsRequest()
  {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertEquals(
      'Qnsi\StaticBunde\Controller\StaticController:indexAction',
      $client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));
  }

  public function testRouteToRootExists()
  {  
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
  }
}
?>
```

So far, I figured out I need to use `setUpBeforeClass()` and initialize my variables there. But I don't really know how. I tried

```
private $client;
private $crawler;
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
}
```

and different combination, but I can't figure it out.

I know it's my lack of good php foundations, but this is how I prefer to learn. By tweaking and learning from example. Sadly, it's hard for me to find a good tests examples on `github` in `Symfony`, so I had to came here and bother you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to init something before each test, then use setUp method:

```
public function setUp() 
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
}
```

Comment: If I do this, my tests run with 2 Errors, and my 2 functions complain that there is `Undefined variable: client`

Comment: Use $this->client in tests (not $client)

`public function testRouteToRootExists()
  {  
    $this->assertTrue(200 === $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
//Check status code only, because request is already done in setUp
  }`

Comment: can you show me how to rewrite using setUpBeforeClass()? I thought it would be simple substitution but it's not. I need setUpBeforeClass, because I only want crawler to make one Get request and not every request for every test I have.

Comment: Properties client and crawler can be static:

`private static $client;
private static $crawler;`
then you can define them in setUpBeforeClass:
`public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    static::$client = static::createClient();
    static::$crawler = static::$client->request('GET', '/');
}`
And after that use them in tests:
`public function testRouteToRootExists()
{
    $this->assertTrue(200 === static::$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}`